# Create blogging system for my website

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter-2, blogs

I have a website created with `CodeIgniter 2` and i would like to add a blogging system which give to registered users the possibility to create their blogs like `user1.domain.com`.

How can i do that, and there is a possibility to use `Wordpress` but automatically ?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to create a blog on wordpress thru CI?

Comment: yes, exactly, every registered user on my website can create a blog as sub domain

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CodeIgniter or Wordpress. 
If you want to do it with CodeIgniter, you need to develop it, create tables, controllers, models and views.

But you can save the time and use Wordpress without any problem. You just need to install it on your page and you can use it only for bloging.

**It depends of you!**

Comment: The problem is that every user choose a username and confirm blog creation. Finally he get a blog with address like `user1.domain.com`, `user2.domain.com`, and so on. so that is not for one time

Comment: Aha... You want to create a subdomain for every user that want to create his blog?
It is more complex, and I don't think that you can do it with Wordpress. So you need to create one application that you will let users to create a blog, and when you will create subdomain for him.

Comment: I found something interesting , it's called `Wordpress Multisites` which allow to create for every end user his blog... but to add new blog, i should use admin pag. but i want to add new blog automatically using PHP..

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-wordpress-multisite-a-network-of-websites-at-your-fingertips/